# Execute service with retrofit 2 sending data in header

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-studio, retrofit2

I am learning to use retrofit, to consume Webservices, I have no problems in executing the @GET, @POST methods but now I have to execute a service where the token is sent, I really do not know how to do it, but I use POSTMAN where this field token I send from Headers in the Authorization key. I have seen other examples where OkHttpClient is used but I can not think of how to implement it.

So I execute my service with retrofit, to this same one the token in the head should be sent to him.

```
@GET(Constants.Retrofit.SURE_DO_YOU_LIKE_PRODUCTS)
    Call<List<RelatedProducts>> getProductSureDoYouLike();
```

and this is my service in POSTMAN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@GET(Constants.Retrofit.SURE_DO_YOU_LIKE_PRODUCTS)
Call<List<RelatedProducts>> getProductSureDoYouLike(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

If all requests require a `Content-Type` you could modify your `Retrofit` builder to include the header on every request:

```
OkHttpClient client;// = new OkHttpClient();

OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()

                   //Add this to include header in every request
                   .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build(); 
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }).build();

        client = builder.build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(NetworkConstants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

Then your request would be:

```
@GET(Constants.Retrofit.SURE_DO_YOU_LIKE_PRODUCTS)
Call<List<RelatedProducts>> getProductSureDoYouLike(@Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

You would then call like so:

```
apiService.getProductSureDoYouLike("token");
```

Comment: It looks good, but just as the type of content you put in the OkHttpClient can be done with Authorization as well, only some services will require token. @MichaelStoddart